# How to locate coding error in vuejs SPA with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I try to build a vue SPA and encounter this error

> vite v2.9.15 building for production...
> ✓ 124 modules transformed.
> [rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Assigning to rvalue (3271:44)
> file: /ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/src/components/RecipeEditor.vue:3271:44
> error during build:
> SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue (3271:44)
> at Parser.pp$4.raise (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19738:13)
> at Parser.pp$7.toAssignable (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18231:12)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeAssign (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18754:21)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19209:28)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseExprAtom (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19072:41)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseExprSubscripts (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18905:19)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeUnary (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18871:17)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseExprOps (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18798:19)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeConditional (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18781:19)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeAssign (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18748:19)

The builder points to line 3271 but I am pretty sure that there is not right hand variable assignation i.e. no error here.
To confirm my thinking, as it is in a rather long function that returns a value I decide to **comment** this function and to replace it by a very short one returning a number, like this.

```
function currentTemperature(time, time_step) {
    return 373; 
}
```

The program continues to compile pretty well with npm run dev

But npm run build returns the same error still pointing on the same line that is now **in a comment**.
My question is how to locate my error as the builder returns an invalid location ?
I am using Visual Studio Code
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: "Assigning to rvalue" usually means you're using `=` instead of `==` when doing a comparison.  As for where the error is I can't say, but my _guess_ would be it's returning you the line from the built production file making a search in your local dev file unreliable. I at least hope knowing what the rvalue error is helps you track it down

Comment: Thank you for the information. It will help next time. For this time I restarted from a previous version of the file.

Comment: BTW what would be the regular expression to find it ?

Comment: I encountered this problem three or four times. Each time, I could not locate the problem easily. The problem is in the template not in the script. To locate it, I removed piece after piece of code in the template, running the build each time. To finally locate the problem in a few remaining lines. It was never the use of = instead of ==, but rather some invisible char. I had to rewrite the piece of code each time. The address indicated is not valid.

Comment: I eventually made out that the error was introduced by the prettier code formatter but I could not find what it was exactly. Using volar formatter instead didn't produce the error.